# How can I remove checkbox key values from a query string?

Tags: php, html, web-services, forms

I have checkboxes in a form, I am posting to a php form processor. My form processor sends a get request to a web service. The request needs to each check box similar to this ?services=Chin&services=Neck&services=Back&location=5

with no key value, but with my php code, it is outputting a [] after each service.

```
//build query string
$fields = array('services' => $services,
            'location' => $location,
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email,
            'emailconfirm' => $email,
            'phone' => $telephone,
            'comments' => $message);

$url = "fakewebaddress?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){

    $curl_handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

}
```

my html boxes look like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Leg" />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Chest" />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Neck" />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Back" />
```

How can I fix it to get the output I need?

Comment: how about you print $services and see what it looks like

Comment: What label tag are you closing in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Services is an array that is why you are getting `[]` after each one. If it wasn't, the last `service` in the GET would be replacing all the others.

The way you want to do it will not work because each of the `services` values will be over writing the previous.

Why not in your webservice just loop through the services array for all the checked values?

See http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html for more info.

**EDIT**:

For what you are wanting (not sure how it will work but it is what you are wanting).

```
$url = str_replace('services[]', 'services', $url);
```

So do

```
//build query string
$fields = array('services' => $services,
            'location' => $location,
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email,
            'emailconfirm' => $email,
            'phone' => $telephone,
            'comments' => $message);

$url = "fakewebaddress?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");
$url = str_replace('services[]', 'services', $url);
// or use this if the [] is encoded
$url = str_replace('services%5B%5D', 'services', $url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm pretty beginner with my dev skills, so maby I didn't totally understand your response. I know that it is an array, so I'm wondering if there is a way to construct the query and remove the [] out of it. Were you saying make the data collector it gets sent to loop through? I can't do that because I didn't build it and can't access it, so I need to make sure it gets sent the data correctly.

Comment: @Evan what webservice are you sending too? I am not sure how an API would accept duplicate elements and not overwrite the previous one. If you MUST send it that way then do the array loop through on your code.

Comment: It's an internal one created by a dev at my company in VB. Many external vendors are using it and the data gets sent that way, so I need to make mine be able to as well. It currently works in js, but need it to in php for some other uses. Can you please point me in the right direction of looping through the array?

Comment: @Evan can you post the URL that is being generated. or atleast the query string

Comment: Sure. This is what I get, ?services%5B0%5D=Chin&services%5B1%5D=Chest&services%5B2%5D=Neck&location=13&firstname=FakeFirst&lastname=FakeLast&email  and this is what I need, .php?services=Chin&services=Neck&services=Back&location=5&firstname=testing12490u8&lastname=testing

Comment: Ok so I got it to work using this. $url = "http://webservice.aspx?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");
 $checkboxes = array('%5B0%5D',
    '%5B1%5D',
    '%5B2%5D',
    '%5B3%5D',
    '%5B4%5D',
    '%5B5%5D',
    '%5B6%5D',
    '%5B7%5D',
    '%5B8%5D',
    '%5B94%5D',
    '%5B10%5D');
 $url2 = str_replace($checkboxes, '', $url); but now I wonder is there a way to make it so any number in there works like a wildcard rather than doing each one?

Comment: @Evan I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: So right now I have 11 Checkboxes on my forms to inquire about different services, therefore the $checkboxes array has 0-11. I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like %5B*%5D where the asterisk would be a wild card representing any number. That way I could easily add more checkboxes without having to edit the processing file. Any ideas?

Comment: @Evan I have added more code to explain. What you are doing with the checkboxes I don't understand. You will want to use my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "fakewebaddress?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");

$url = str_replace(urlencode('services[]'), 'services', $url);
```